# Android if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) Freezes app

Tags: android, if-statement, android-mediaplayer

I have two buttons that make sounds but if one button is pressed while the other is still playing, they both play at the same time. I'm trying to use an if statement to check if there is a mediaPlayer playing and then stop it.

```
MediaPlayer mp;
```

Later on in the onClick for the first button

```
if (mp.isPlaying() == true) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
}
mp= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound1);
mp.start();
```

The problem is that when I click on that button, the app freezes and Eclipse highlights the line

```
if (mp.isPlaying() == true) {
```

Logcat shows nothing is wrong, error-wise at least, and the debug tag says "mp$1.onClick(View) line: 30"
Anyone know what's going on or how I could could fix this?

Comment: I've used the MP a lot for one of my apps and even used that API entry for exactly the same purpose and I don't recall running into this issue. Perhaps you're leaving out some minor detail?

Comment: It's inside the onClick for a button if that means anything

Comment: There is probably a more simple explanation but would you happen to be accessing `mp` on a different thread then it was created? The onClick happens on the main UI event thread. Did you start the sound on some other thread (AsyncTask maybe)?

Comment: I have the MediaPlayer mp; right after the public class Main { and before the onCreate stuff.